# How to add 'n' number of multiple series lines in high charts dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I have plotted one line in a chart. I need to plot points dynamically. Below is the my code in jsfiddle. I need to plot 24 hours of day with 30 minutes constant interval along x axis and stop names on the y axis.
Please help.

```js
        var Arcategories = ['Udhna Darwaza', 'Kharwar Nagar', 'Satya Nagar', 'Udhna Tran Rasta', 'Udhna Bus Stand', 'Udhna Academy', 'Laxmi Narayan Temple', 'Daksheswar Mahadev', 'Pandesara G.I.D.C.', 'Kamnath Mahadev', 'Navin Flourine', 'Bhestan Naher', 'Bhagwati Industrial Estate', 'Unn Naka', 'Unn Industrial Estate', 'Unn Char Rasta', 'Green Park', 'Sachin G.I.D.C.'];
        var timeArray = ["06:00:00", "06:05:00", "06:13:00", "06:19:00", "06:26:00", "06:32:00", "06:38:00", "06:45:00", "06:52:00", "06:59:00", "07:06:00", "07:13:00", "07:20:00", "07:28:00", "07:34:00", "07:40:00", "07:46:00", "07:52:00"];
        resulttime = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
          var hms = timeArray[i].split(':');



          var d = new Date(); // creates a Date Object using the clients current time



          var st = [Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), hms[0], hms[1], hms[2]), "00"];

          resulttime.push([st[0], i]);
        }
        console.log(resulttime)
        Highcharts.chart('container', {


          xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            opposite: true,
            gridLineWidth: 1
          },

          yAxis: {
            categories: Arcategories,
            reversed: true
          },

          series: [{
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            },
            data: resulttime
          }]

        });
```

```css
  #container {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

link: http://jsfiddle.net/b8whv9vx/1/

Comment: The jsfiddle seems to work as described. What is it not doing that it should be?

Comment: You can add a series with [chart.addSeries()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.addSeries) function. So if you need n new series, you need to call n time addSeries()

Comment: Thanks it worked me..

Comment: Now i have plotted  nseries  but now i facing the performance issue for loading 50 series it is taking more than 4 minutes i need to plot 200 series in my chart..